# How to cut the first line and paste it on new file with CMD

Tags: cmd, move, lines

I want move the first 2 lines from one file to one other. Does anyone knows how? `file1.txt > file2.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "count=2"
<file1.txt (
  for /l %%i in (1,1,%count%) do (
    set "line="
    set /p "line="
    echo/!line!
  )
) >file2.txt
more +2 file1.txt > file3.txt
del file1.txt
ren file3.txt file1.txt
```

Comment: i want to move the 2 line not copy that to the other file